# proving linear subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $A,B$ be matrices of order $m\times n$. Prove that the row space $\ W_{A+B}$ of the matrix $A + B$ is contained in the sub space that is created by the rows of $A$ and the rows of $B$.

(with this i am having a big trouble especially): prove the following inequality: $p(A+B) \leq p(A)+p(B)$ and give two examples of two matrices of order $2\times2$ that fullfil $p(A+B) > p(A)$ AND $p(A+B)> p(B)$ (both questions are one question)

I really don't know how to prove it mathmatically (both of them) and i don't know how to write it mathmatically correctly. i'll apreciate if you could show me the correct way of writing mathmatical proves.

thank you very much and sorry that i couldn't write what i tried, because i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: And what is $p$?

Comment: rank of the solutions space, as far as i know

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $a_i$ be the rows of $A$ and $b_i$ be the rows of $B$. You are told to show that the span of the $m$ vectors $a_1+b_1, a_2+b_2, \ldots, a_m+b_m$ is contained in the span of the $2m$ vectors $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_m, b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_m$.